# How can I access the value of a custom attribute in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following link with a "data-id" attribute.

```html
<a href="" class id="tooltip" data-id="38">Link</a>
```

In this case the "38" from the data-id attribute should get send with ajax to my server-sided script. The problem is that the "data-id" value isn´t get picked up.

```js
jQuery(function($) { 
  var html_data = $(this).attr("data-id");
                      
  $("#tooltip").tooltip({
    content: function(response) {
      $.ajax({ 
        url: "/datenbank/itemscript.php",
        data: { 'var': html_data },
        type: "GET"
      }).then(function( data ) {
        response( data );
      });
    },
    items: "*"
  });
});
```

If I change this for test purposes

```
var html_data = $(this).attr("data-id");
```

to

```
var html_data = $.data(this, 'id', 38);
```

the script is working. Why isn't `$(this).attr("data-id");` picked up my data-id value?

Comment: `this` in the document.ready handler will be the `window` object. You need to provide an actual selector to target the `#tooltip` element. `$.data(this, 'id', 38);` is only working by sheer blind luck as it returns the value you are hard-coding as a data attribute on the window: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Comment: `$.data(this, 'id', 38)` does not find the value, it will *set* the data-id attribute to 38 and return the value that was set.

Comment: I understand, thanks @Rory McCrossan.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the following methods:

1.) Access the data-id attribute direct by the element. The element has an ID so you can access the data-id value like this:

```
$("#tooltip").attr("data-id");
```

2.) You give each element a class and bind an onclick-event to this class:

```
<a href="" class="jsClickLink" data-id="10">Link</a>
<a href="" class="jsClickLink" data-id="11">Link</a>
<a href="" class="jsClickLink" data-id="12">Link</a>
...

jQuery(document.ready(function($){
  $(".jsClickLink").on("click", function(){
     console.log("ID:" + $(this).attr("data-id");
  })
})
```

Comment: jquery has a build in dataset function [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/). There is no need to use `attr()`. Also you can skip the class in this case and use the attribute as a selector.

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to work, you should move

```
var html_data = $(this).attr("data-id");
```

inside `$("#tooltip").tooltip({` method

or you can do somthing like that

```
jQuery(document.ready(function($){
   var html_data = $('#tooltip').attr("data-id");

   $("#tooltip").tooltip({
     content: function(response) {
        $.ajax({ 
              url: "/datenbank/itemscript.php",
              data: { 'var': html_data },
              type: "GET"
       }).then(function( data ) {
              response( data );
       });
     },
    items: "*"
   });
});
```